# ArrayList with unique classes

Tags: java

I have an `Entity` class, which has an ArrayList (called "effects") of subclasses of a class, `StatusEffect`. The ArrayList could have different subclasses of `StatusEffect` like `Burning`, `Frozen`, `Nauseated`. I also have a method, `addEffect()` which adds a subclass of status effect to the ArrayList using "`effects.add(new SUBCLASS-NAME())`". My question is how I could make it so that if the arrayList already has a SubClass of one type in it, it won't add the new effect. For example, if the ArrayList has the "`Burning`" class in it already, and I try to use `addEffect(),` it won't do anything because the ArrayList already has the class "Burning" in it.

What I tried was

```java
protected void addEffect(StatusEffect effect) {
    if(!getEffects().contains(effect.getClass())) {
        effects.add(effect);
    }
    else {
        out.println(getName() + " was already affected by " + effect.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: From what you describe, it sound like the `StatusEffect`s are multitions (each sub-class of `StatusEffect` is a singleton). --- If we need a collection without duplicates, we can use a `Set` instead of a `List`

Comment: You either need a separate set or list of the classes, not the instances. Or iterate through the list and check the class of each instance against the instance of the new class. Currently you have the effect instances in there but check if a class is in there, which it never is.

Comment: How is `equals()` implemented in `StatusEffect` and its respective subclasses?

Comment: Use a `Set`.  As dan1st points out, you need a correctly implemented `equals()` method or the Set won't work.  An `enum` might be appropriate here.

Comment: @dan1st I haven't used equals() in StatusEffect or its subclasses

Comment: _Why_ do you need the ArrayList to allow "anything" for its first addition, but only "the same class as before" for subsequent additions, though? What problem does this approach solve? (because it's quite likely that this smooths over a symptom of an underlying design problem instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single object per class in your data structure, you can use a `Map`. The key of the `Map` would be a `Class` representing the effect type and the value would be the concrete effect:

```java
Map<Class<? extends StatusEffect>, StatusEffect> effects = new HashMap<>();

//insert only if not already there
effects.putIfAbsent(effect.getClass(), effect);
//insert or overwrite if already there
effects.put(effect.getClass(), effect);
//remove
effects.remove(effect.getClass());
//or
effects.remove(Burning.class);
//iterate
for(StatusEffect effect : effects.values()){
    //... 
}
```

The nature of `Map`s only allows a single value per key.

If you want to preserve order, you can use a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap`.